# Users cannot deploy to Nexus 3 using maven, only using the UI

Tags: maven-3, sonatype, nexus3

I am writing instructions on how to set up Travis CI to deploy to our local Nexus 3 maven repository. I am testing my own instructions to make sure everything works. I have discovered that I cannot upload any artifacts using maven unless I use administrator credentials. As a regular user, I can upload using the provided web UI, but not maven. 
All the users have full admin rights over the hosted repositories as well as the nx-component-upload privilege which enables the UI upload. 
I must be missing something. The error message I get when running maven deploy is:

```
   org.apache.maven.shared.transfer.artifact.deploy.ArtifactDeployerException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact nz.org.riskscape:rsum_api:jar:1.0 from/to juglab-release (https://dais-maven/repository/juglab-release/): Failed to transfer file https://dais-maven/repository/juglab-release/nz/org/riskscape/rsum_api/1.0/rsum_api-1.0.jar with status code 401
```

Thanx in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. The problem was in the settings file, the username had been misstyped.